# Text in columns on canvas loses columns in postscript

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

Tcl/Tk 8.6.13 on macos 10.15 Catalina.

I'm placing lots of text on a canvas, saving to PostScript, and generating a PDF from that with GhostScript or the Preview app.

On the canvas, I can make a multiline text block with tabs between words to make columns. It looks good on the canvas.

Displaying the resulting PostScript or PDF files shows no columns, just words next to each other.

The canvas looks like this:

[image: snapshot of canvas]

The PDF looks like this:

[image: snapshot of pdf]

Here's my test script:

```
set PAGEHEIGHT 11
set PAGEWIDTH  8.5
font create troman -family Times-Roman -size 11 
canvas .c1 -height ${PAGEHEIGHT}i -width ${PAGEWIDTH}i
pack .c1 -side top -expand 1
set cols "qwert\tpoipoipoi\nas\tdfghj\nzxcvbn\tbnmbnm"
.c1 create text 2i 2i -font troman -text $cols 
after 200
.c1 postscript -file out.ps
```

The relevant section of the PostScript file shows this, a tab character in the string:

```
/Times-Roman findfont 11 scalefont ISOEncode setfont
0.000 0.000 0.000 setrgbcolor AdjustColor
0 143.858407079646 611.141592920354 [
[(qwert\tpoipoipoi)]
[(as\tdfghj)]
[(zxcvbn\tbnmbnm)]
] 13 -0.5 0.5 0 false DrawText
```

Am I missing an option somewhere, or this expected behaviour?
Thanks!

(I've also tried embedding a `text` widget in the canvas. Again, it looks great on the canvas, and I can even change the tab stops. But this time, the PostScript output just shows a black box for the text window. I don't really care about this situation, just thought I should mention it, in case it's an actual problem.)

Comment: Right.  Tabs are totally unreliable with variable-pitch fonts.  May I ask why you are generating PDF files this way?  tcl has never been state of the art.  There are excellent PDF libraries available for Python, or PHP, or Javascript that will give you maximum control.

Comment: @KJ Yes, PS doesn't know about the tab character - and that's the problem. I'm not generating it, Tk is passing it through, even tho it handles it nicely on its own canvas. I expected the generated PS output to look like the canvas display. It doesn't. Was hoping for some Tcl/Tk experts to comment here, but nothing yet. Thanks!